# Can't connect to PEAP with wpa_supplicant on Arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi-configuration, wpa-supplicant, peap

I've been searching around for how to connect to PEAP and there's lot's of info out there, but I can't seem to connect and my University tech support is no help(I'm not really surprised).

Basically I can connect on my main Arch OS visually with Gnome.  Rowan University's support page shows the setup for Ubuntu and I've been using that to try and get my config right.  This is what they've supplied:

[image: Ubuntu PEAP Config]

and this is what's in my config file:

[image: wpa_supplicant config]

The output of wpa_supplicant with -d:
[image: wpa_supplicant -d 1]
[image: wpa_supplicant -d 2]

Any help you can give is appreciated and let me know if you need the outputs of any commands.

Comment: How did you generate that 'psk'? WPA-Enterprise does not use PSKs.

Comment: I used wpa_passphrase, I had a plaintext password in before and it still wouldn't connect

Comment: If you're successfully using NetworkManager on your main system, is there a reason not to simply copy the same profile to NetworkManager in the new system?

Comment: Hmm I guess I could.  The new system is for a mining rig so it's on a usb drive.  Are there any bonuses or drawbacks to NetworkManager over wpa_supplicant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used wpa_passphrase, I had a plaintext password in before and it still wouldn't connect

For PEAP you *really* must use the `password=` setting.

There is no PSK in WPA-Enterprise, and although the password may be hashed for MSCHAPv2, it would use a completely different hash than WPA-Personal PSKs do. Therefore `wpa_passphrase` is useless here.

If it "still wouldn't connect" with a password, then it wouldn't connect for a different reason.

> Are there any bonuses or drawbacks to NetworkManager over wpa_supplicant?

NetworkManager will just drive wpa_supplicant behind the scenes, and indeed all the parameters you find in the connection profile in /etc are very similar to raw wpa_supplicant config.

So in your case the advantage is just that you can copy/paste the config, not much more.

Comment: As far as I know – even for WPA-Personal, prehashing the passphrase into a PSK will mean you won't be able to use SAE authentication in WPA3 in the future. So you'll have to choose local security vs network security eventually.

Comment: It took me a bit, but I managed to get a connection.  I found where the config files are stored form this post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155893.  Then I used the Arch Wiki NetworkManager page to get a connection established.  Thanks for all the help!